# SQL SELECT and make certain columns in the data returned blank

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called `empSchedule`.
`empSchedule` consists of `name`, `task`, and `visibility`.
`visibility` is either 'public' or 'private'.

I'd like to select everything in the table whether `visibility` is 'public' or 'private'. However, if `visibility` is 'private', I'd like to make the value in `task` blank.

For example, I'd like to see a table like this using SELECT

```
+----------+-------+------------+
| name     | task  | visibility |
+----------+-------+------------+
| john     | HW    | public     |
| james    | TextC | public     |
| bill     |       | private    |
+----------+-------+------------+
```

The query below does not work because it excludes all the private rows.

```
SELECT name, task, visibility
FROM empSchedule
WHERE visibility = 'public';
```

I am learning SQL, so I would like to see alternative answers if what I am looking for can't be done.

Answer (score 4):

You just need one small `case` expression

```
SELECT name, 
       CASE visibility WHEN 'private' THEN '' ELSE task END task,
       visibility
FROM empSchedule
WHERE visibility IN ('public', 'private')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `IF` statement in `SQL` query as shown below:

```
SELECT `name`, 
  IF(`visibility` = 'private', "", `task`) END task,
  `visibility`
FROM `empSchedule`
```

**Definition and Usage**

The `IF()` function returns one value if a condition is **TRUE**, or another value if a condition is **FALSE**.

**Note:** The `IF()` function can return either a string or a numeric value.

**Syntax**

```
IF(condition, value_if_true, value_if_false)
```